# What is the function that is not a binary function called?

Tags: abstract-algebra, definition

A binary operation is a calculation involving two elements of the set and returning another element of the set. Suppose it doesn't return an element of the set. What is the function called?

For example subtraction in the natural numbers. a - b with $a, b \in \mathbb{N}$ can return an element outside $\Bbb N$.

Comment: For example? ${}{}{}$

Comment: I believe just a binary function. When it returns an element of the original set, a binary function is then called a binary operation

Comment: @BabakS. Added an example

Comment: In a vector space multiplication by a scalar is a binary operation which is not of the kind you suggest.

Comment: @DavidH Incorrect by definition.

Comment: @MarkBennet I don't understand how that answers my question

Comment: I don't think this has a name other than a function of two variables.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese But then it wouldn't be an algebraic structure...

Comment: It is called a function.

Comment: What do you mean? Who says such a thing is an algebraic structure? Consider $f : \mathbb{Z}_p\times \mathbb{Z}_p \to \{\operatorname{Toast}\}$, $(m, n) \mapsto \operatorname{Toast}$. What is algebraic about this?

Comment: Thanks Michael, you beat me to it. Found that out seconds ago after re-reading something on Wikipedia

Comment: @Jossie I put my comment as a comment because it isn't an answer - you have begun with the assertion "a binary operation is ..." - the expression "binary operation" is used more widely than you have suggested in the post - I just wanted to alert you to that fact.

Comment: It is the binary operation I speak of. It simply multiplies all elements in the vector by 2. For example the vector 2(2,4) is a binary operation. It can be defined more rigorously, but that is not the purpose here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't have a specific name for when the returned value does not come from the same space as the inputs. To see why this idea doesn't deserve its own word, let's look at it more carefully.

If we want to let our reader know that the $-$ operation defined on naturals numbers doesn't return a natural number, we simply have to give them the function's signature, $-:\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Z}$.

In general we write $f:A \to B$ if $f$ takes inputs in $A$ and returns values in $B$. It is good practice to include the function signature in the definition of a function, especially when it is not immediately obvious what the $A,B$ should be. Because writers are typically very good about including the codomain $B$ explicitly when defining a function, there is not a good reason to give a name to types of functions $f: A \times A\to B$ where $B \neq A$.

In general, stick to clearly specifying the function signature whenever it is needed.

Comment: ℕ×ℕ→ℤ << So writing something like that and calling it a binary operation is an error?

Comment: No, this would still be a binary operation. Binary refers to the number of inputs. In this case $-$ requires two inputs $n_1-n_2$. Unary is for one input, binary is for two, ternary is for three. We  would say $A$ is **closed** under $f$ if we knew the $f(a_1,a_2) \in A$ for all $a_1,a_2 \in A$. In the case of subtraction, $\mathbb{N}$ is not closed under $-$, since the difference can be negative.

Comment: But under my defintion, it says "doesn't return an element of the set" and thus it isn't a binary function.

Comment: @Jossie If that is your definition, then it would not be considered a binary function. However, the more widely accepted definition of binary function is all $f:A\times B\to C$, not just $f:A\times A \to A$.